# How to validate a wizard form with php and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, session, cookies

A brief explanation of how this simple jQuery wizard works

- Sessions are used to save data for each step.
- consists of a session variable to save in what step we are.
- consists of a session variable to store the form data.
- Each time we change the step we save the data of the form and the step in session with an ajax request.
- If the data is updated the data is retrieved from the session.

**This wizard form consists of 3 steps.**

As I can correct the errors and validate the form with php if there is a field without data do not let go to the next step, until all fields of the form are completed by the user.

There are warning errors in each of the form fields in each text input shows me a warning message.

> Notice: Undefined index: datos_form in **C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\wizar.php on line 229**

I would like to add a cookie to the session where the steps are saved to avoid erasing the data stored in the session in case the browser is closed in error, create a session cookie with a validation time of 30 days.

now to remove the cookie from the data saved by the user create a cancel button, the cancel button will delete the cookie, including the data saved in the session.

> **My complete code:**

**wizar.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

// check if there is a previous step.
if ( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['__paso__']) ) {
    $paso = $_SESSION['datos_form']['__paso__'];
}
// if there is no previous step we set step 1.
else{
    $paso = '1';
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form por pasos</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    mostrar_paso(<?= $paso; ?>);        
});


function animacion(caso){
    switch(caso) {
        case 1:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px 0px`);
            break;
        case 2:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px -16px`);
            break;
        case 3:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px -32px`);
            break;
        default:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px 0px`);
    };
};

function mostrar_paso(paso)
{

    var data = $( "#form" ).serialize();

    var url = 'saveTemp.php?paso=' + paso;

    var valor_radio = $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').next("label").text();


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data
    })
    .done(function( resp ) {

        $('.step').css( "display", "none" );

        $('#paso'+paso).fadeIn("slow");

        $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);

        animacion(paso);
    });
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="setup">
    <ul class="backdrop">
        <li class="process item1">step 1</li>
        <li class="process item2">step 2</li>
        <li class="process item3">FINALIZE</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<form id="form" action="procesar.php">
    <div id="paso1" class="step">
        <input type="text" name="campo1" value="<?= $_SESSION['datos_form']['campo1']; ?>">

        <select class="form-select" name="sexo">
            <?php 
                if( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['sexo']) ) {
                    $sexo = $_SESSION['datos_form']['sexo'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$sexo.'" selected="selected">'.$sexo.'</option>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<option disabled selected="selected">I am...</option>';
                }
            ?>
            <option value="Mem">Men</option>
            <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
            <option value="I prefer not to say">I prefer not to say</option>        
        </select>

        <?php 
            if( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['condiciones']) ) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" checked>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="condiciones">';
            }
        ?>
        ...


onclick="mostrar_paso('numero de paso') -->
        <a href="#2" onclick="mostrar_paso(2)">continuar</a>
    </div>
    <div id="paso2" class="step">

        <?php
            $r =array(
                    1 => 'Product 1',
                    2 => 'Product 2',
                    3 => 'Product 3',
                );

            foreach ($r as $key => $value) 
            {
                if( $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] == $key ) {
                    echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"  checked="checked" >';
                    echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >';
                    echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
                }
            }
        ?>

        <a href="#1" onclick="mostrar_paso(1)">Atras</a>
        <a href="#3" onclick="mostrar_paso(3)">continuar</a>
    </div>
    <div id="paso3" class="step">
        <div id="div_producto"></div><br>

        <input type="text" name="campo3" value="<?= $_SESSION['datos_form']['campo3']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="cancel">
        <a href="#2" onclick="mostrar_paso(2)">Atras</a>
        <input type="submit" name="Terminar">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**saveTemp.php**

> **Note:** This file is responsible for saving the step and data of the form.

```
<?php
session_start();
// We save the form data in a session variable
$_SESSION['datos_form'] = $_POST;
// we added the step also to the array, you can not use this name (__paso__) as name in the form
$_SESSION['datos_form']['__paso__'] = $_GET['paso'];
```

Comment: @mplungjan I do not understand, I have detailed in my question the necessary, how it works so that they arrive at the idea and the error that I am presenting. It is not clear?

Comment: post your wizar.php instead of form.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As I can correct the errors and validate the form with php if there is
>   a field without data do not let go to the next step, until all fields
>   of the form are completed by the user.

You need to code validation rules under saveTemp.php something like this :

```
<?php
session_start();
//form validation
switch($_GET['paso']){
    case 2:
        if(empty($_POST['campo1'])){//you may add any validation rule you want here
            die(json_encode(array('status' => FALSE,'message' => 'please fill campo ....')));
        }
        if(empty($_POST['sexo'])){
            die(json_encode(array('status' => FALSE,'message' => 'please select sexo ....')));
        }
        if(empty($_POST['condiciones'])){
            die(json_encode(array('status' => FALSE,'message' => 'please select condiciones ....')));
        }
        break;
    case 3: //step 2 validation here
        if(empty($_POST['radio'])){//you may add any validation rule you want here
            die(json_encode(array('status' => FALSE,'message' => 'please fill radio1 ....')));
        }
    break;
}

// We save the form data in a session variable
$_SESSION['datos_form'] = $_POST;
// we added the step also to the array, you can not use this name (__paso__) as name in the form
$_SESSION['datos_form']['__paso__'] = $_GET['paso'];

die(json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,'message' => 'Temporary saved....')));
```

and then check response under ajax call for status, so you need to change ajax call like this:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function( resp ) {
        if(resp.status)
        {
            $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
            $('#paso'+paso).fadeIn("slow");
            $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);
            animacion(paso);
        }else{
            var old_paso = paso-1;
            alert(resp.message);
            $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
            $('#paso'+old_paso).fadeIn("slow");
            $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);
            animacion(old_paso);            
        }
    });
```

notice that I add "dataType" to your ajax call and set it to json

> There are warning errors in each of the form fields in each text input
>   shows me a warning message.

that because you did not check for existence of variable before getting its value, the code you post is form.php but warning complain about wizar.php line number 229, check that line and use empty function just like the rest of your code

here is a sample wizar.php without notice/warning:

```
<?php

session_start();

// check if there is a previous step.
if ( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['__paso__']) ) {
    $paso = $_SESSION['datos_form']['__paso__'];
}
// if there is no previous step we set step 1.
else{
    $paso = '1';
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form por pasos</title>
<style type="text/css">
.backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    width: 630px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(//drh.img.digitalriver.com/DRHM/Storefront/Site/avast/cm/images/avast/2014/breadcrumb-3.png) no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.step {
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}

.step-1 {
    display: block;
}

.setup {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
    background-color: rgba(29, 36, 36, 0.25);
}


.process {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.process.item2 {
  padding-left: 190px;
}

.process.item3 {
  padding-left: 400px;
}

.process.item4 {
  padding-left: 580px;
}

.process.item5 {
  padding-left: 690px;
}

.process.item6 {
  padding-left: 790px;
}

ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.step{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
    $('#paso'+<?= $paso; ?>).fadeIn("slow");
    $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);
    animacion(<?= $paso; ?>);        
});


function animacion(caso){
    switch(caso) {
        case 1:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px 0px`);
            break;
        case 2:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px -16px`);
            break;
        case 3:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px -32px`);
            break;
        default:
            $(".backdrop").css("background-position", `0px 0px`);
    };
};

function mostrar_paso(paso)
{

    var data = $( "#form" ).serialize();

    var url = 'saveTemp.php?paso=' + paso;

    var valor_radio = $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').next("label").text();


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function( resp ) {
        if(resp.status)
        {
            $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
            $('#paso'+paso).fadeIn("slow");
            $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);
            animacion(paso);
        }else{
            var old_paso = paso-1;
            alert(resp.message);
            $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
            $('#paso'+old_paso).fadeIn("slow");
            $('#div_producto').html(valor_radio);
            animacion(old_paso);            
        }
    });
};

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="setup">
    <ul class="backdrop">
        <li class="process item1">step 1</li>
        <li class="process item2">step 2</li>
        <li class="process item3">FINALIZE</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<form id="form" action="procesar.php">
    <div id="paso1" class="step">
        <input type="text" name="campo1" value="<?= (!empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['campo1'])) ? $_SESSION['datos_form']['campo1'] : '' ; ?>">

        <select class="form-select" name="sexo">
            <?php 
                if( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['sexo']) ) {
                    $sexo = $_SESSION['datos_form']['sexo'];
                    echo '<option value="'.$sexo.'" selected="selected">'.$sexo.'</option>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<option disabled selected="selected">I am...</option>';
                }
            ?>
            <option value="Mem">Men</option>
            <option value="Woman">Woman</option>
            <option value="I prefer not to say">I prefer not to say</option>        
        </select>

        <?php 
            if( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['condiciones']) ) {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="condiciones" checked>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="condiciones">';
            }
        ?>
        ...


onclick="mostrar_paso('numero de paso') -->
        <a href="#2" onclick="mostrar_paso(2)">continuar</a>
    </div>
    <div id="paso2" class="step">

        <?php
            $r =array(
                    1 => 'Product 1',
                    2 => 'Product 2',
                    3 => 'Product 3',
                );

            foreach ($r as $key => $value) 
            {
                if( !empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['radio']) AND $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] == $key ) {
                    echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"  checked="checked" >';
                    echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >';
                    echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
                }
            }
        ?>

        <a href="#1" onclick="mostrar_paso(1)">Atras</a>
        <a href="#3" onclick="mostrar_paso(3)">continuar</a>
    </div>
    <div id="paso3" class="step">
        <div id="div_producto"></div><br>

        <input type="text" name="campo3" value="<?= (!empty($_SESSION['datos_form']['campo3'])) ? $_SESSION['datos_form']['campo3'] : ''; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="cancel">
        <a href="#2" onclick="mostrar_paso(2)">Atras</a>
        <input type="submit" name="Terminar">
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

> I would like to add a cookie to the session where the steps are saved
>   to avoid erasing the data stored in the session in case the browser is
>   closed in error, create a session cookie with a validation time of 30
>   days.

PHP's native session, already using cookie if visitor browser support cookie and the expiration time can be set in php.ini or at runtime by setting [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)

> now to remove the cookie from the data saved by the user create a
>   cancel button, the cancel button will delete the cookie, including the
>   data saved in the session.

And finally use [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) function to delete that cookie under procesar.php file

Comment: my wizard form is only based on the two published files, there is no other dependent file or another linked file.

Comment: how I can correct the errors and as I would have to validate each field of the form, as far as I've tried I've managed to only have errores of warning of php, help me yes.

Comment: as I mentioned there is no more dependent files or files linked to **wizar.php** since the wizard form is based on the 3 steps in the same file **wizar.php** +1 :).

Comment: OK I just code it for you, check my wizar.php and saveTemp.php, you may validate your last step at procesar.php and also consider adding client side validation.

Comment: thanks friend now reviewed :) I do not know how to validate on the server side but you could integrate it and comment on each line its operation so we can continue with new validation but I would have to mix jQuery with the sessions reminds me friend that through the sessions of the data is that the wizard information is saved.

Comment: Here is a basic form validation tutorial : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp